# Basic Go HTTP router

Tags: go, url-routing

I know Gorilla and others have packages that accomplish this, but I'm trying to learn Go by making stuff. In the router below, the first route `/` is for all http methods, the second route `/hello` is only for `GET`, and the third route `hello/:name` has one parameter for all HTTP methods.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", route)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func match(re string, route string) bool {
    match, err := regexp.MatchString(re, route)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return match
}

func route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    route := r.URL.Path
    switch {
    case route == "/":
        home(w, r)
    case route == "/hello" && r.Method == "GET":
        hello(w, r)
    case match("^/hello/([^/]+)$", route) == true:
        var re = regexp.MustCompile("^/hello/([^/]+)$")
        match := re.FindStringSubmatch(route)

        helloName(w, r, match[1])
    default:
        notFound(w, r)
    }
}

// func home, hello, helloName, and notFound
```

How can I make this more efficient? Is it reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can put all of the `regexp.MustCompile`'s into the `func init`, change a few other things, and increase the speed by more than a factor of 50:

```
var routeRegex map[string]*regexp.Regexp

func init() {
    r := make(map[string]string)
    r["helloName"] = "^/hello/([a-zA-Z]+?)$"
    r["helloNameAge"] = "^/hello/([a-zA-Z]+?)/([0-9]+?)$"

    routeRegex = make(map[string]*regexp.Regexp)
    for k, v := range r {
        routeRegex[k] = regexp.MustCompile(v)
    }
}

func match(x string, r string) (bool, []string) {
    if m := routeRegex[x].FindStringSubmatch(r); m != nil {
        return true, m[1:]
    }

    return false, nil
}

func Route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rt := r.URL.Path

    if rt == "/" {
        home(w, r)
    } else if rt == "/hello" && r.Method == "GET" {
        hello(w, r)
    } else if m, p := match("helloName", rt); m {
        helloName(w, r, p[0])
    } else if m, p := match("helloNameAge", rt); m {
        helloNameAge(w, r, p[0], p[1] )
    } else {
        notFound(w, r)
    }
}
```

I benchmarked `func route` with 1) no regex, 2) one regex match, 3) two regex matches, and 4) not matching route / not found.

new solution:

1. 3.6 ns/op
2. 279 ns/op
3. 332 ns/op
4. 212 ns/op

old solution:

1. 3.33 ns/op
2. 16237 ns/op
3. 16479 ns/op
4. 16543 ns/op

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `case x == true` you can use boolean expressions directly,
and write simply:

```
case x:
```

The same regex is written twice here.
What's worse is that the pattern matching is also evaluated twice:

> ```
> case match("^/hello/([^/]+)$", route) == true:
>     var re = regexp.MustCompile("^/hello/([^/]+)$")
> ```

I'm not sure if there's an elegant solution for this situation in Go.
But at the minimum you could move the regex pattern into a variable to avoid typing it twice.

Another alternative is to create a matcher structure,
with a `match` function that will not only match a pattern and return a boolean,
but at the same time also store the sub-string you want to extract.

```
type matcher struct {
    value string
}

func (m *matcher) match(pattern string, route string) bool {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(route)
    if len(matches) < 2 {
        return false
    }

    m.value = matches[1]

    return true
}
```

With the help of this, you could rewrite the `route` function as:

```
func route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    route := r.URL.Path
    m := &matcher{}
    switch {
    case route == "/":
        home(w, r)
    case route == "/hello" && r.Method == "GET":
        hello(w, r)
    case m.match("^/hello/([^/]+)$", route):
        helloName(w, r, m.value)
    default:
        notFound(w, r)
    }
}
```